# Getting "HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: GET" when request is successful

Tags: scala, rest, postman, akka-http

I am working on a Akka-Http project in which I am writing a POST endpoint `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/internal/admin/import` which requires a header with an access token.

My curl request is as follows

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/internal/admin/import' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: text/plain' \
--header 'Authorization: correct-token' \
--data-raw '{  
   "id": 100,  
   "name": "test"  
 }'
```

When the access token is incorrect, I get the http response in the exact format that is expected

```
  "status": {
    "code": 403,
    "error": "authorization_error",
    "details": "Invalid token"
  }
}
```

But as soon as I provide a correct token in the header, the http request is successful, but I get a weird message `HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: GET`.

Just before sending the correct response, I tried to print the json and its correct. My code looks as follows :

```
    onComplete(futureR) {
      case Success(result) =>
        println(s"Success response json is ${Json.toJson(result)}")
        complete(result)
      case Failure(ex) => complete(
        500 -> StatusResponse(ApiStatus(500, None, None))
      )
    }
```

The result I am getting on terminal is `Success response json is {"status":{"code":0}}` which is correct, however in Postman, I keep on getting the error `HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: GET`.

Any pointers to this problem ? TIA

Comment: Isn't there a `method(HttpMethods.GET)` somewhere that rejects all non-GET requests?

Comment: Error `HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: GET`  indicating that there is no post method support for that API endpoint.

Comment: But, if it did not find the api, then it would not have persisted in the database. The record is created successfully in the database, success response is got till the controller, but when I send the response to the `complete` method, it returns this error.

Comment: can you provide your controller code (aka skeleton of how you handling post request)

Comment: I have a similar situation with PUT and DELETE endpoints and basic authentication headers. How did you fix that?